# Git: do not pull deletes into branch?

Tags: git, pull

Lead wanted simpler code reviews (PR's). So branched code into 3 branches. A->B->C.
Then deleting code from A. Deleting the additional code so A will be a simpler code review. Then will make a code review for B, and later C.

Since B is branched from A, then I assume I can never do a pull on it. Is this correct?
Similar but not the same question: 
[How to turn a git branch into fork?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20450537/how-to-turn-a-git-branch-into-fork)

I guess what I should have done is using original code base ABC done this:

```
ABC->A  (delete B and C stuff. Code review A.)
ABC->BC->B  (delete C stuff and code review B)
BC->C (code review the total. Or ABC->C even.)
```

This way changes to ABC could be pulled into A, or B, or C. Correct?

So, given I didn't do that, is there any way to save my code on a Pull or Merge. That is, if I don't Pull into B but do merge B into the EPIC, then will the deletes done in A be applied (not what I want). Or perhaps if I touch every file deleted in A while working on B and C will that save my files and prevent them being deleted on Merge. Afraid I might get burned here. What's the way out? (besides starting all over.)

Comment: Not sure this even makes sense, at least in part because you seem to have some confusion between the concept of a "commit" and a "branch"...

Answer (score 0):

Don't understand the method behind the madness... Why not create a remote branch and get the team to push and pull from the remote branch. When your lead is happy with code then merge to master.

Comment: We do. But he wanted each task (JIRA issue) to be only a few files of changes/adds. So, break down into smaller tasks/branches. If that makes sense.