# If I git push an existing project to a new remote, will it still have the pre-push commits?

Tags: git, github

I read [this SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20450537/how-to-turn-a-git-branch-into-fork), and am in the same situation myself. My question is, if I push the branch to a new remote, will it still have the commits that it had when it was a branch of the original repo?

Comment: you cannot push a project to a remote, you cannot however push a branch. And when you push a branch, you push its commits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. (Really, that's the answer.)

When you have a branch in a local repository,  it's a branch in a local repository. It's never a branch in the remote repo (though you may have remote-tracking branches in local repo). You can push a local branch to any number of remotes.

You can have one upstream branch for every local branch, but it's not remote branch — it's a remote-tracking branch in local repo. But you can also have zero upstream branches. Even if a local branch has an upstream branch that doesn't prevent pushing the branch to any number of remotes.